# How does an irc daemon like Charybdis work?

Tags: centos, irc, daemon

I am pretty new to irc, and am poking around in it to try and understand it.

I am running CentOS 7 on a VM, and have installed charybdis-4.1.1 and atheme-7.2.10-r2, using this marvellous [guide](http://matthughes.io/setting-up-an-irc-server-with-charybdis-and-atheme-updated-for-2018/). However, while the guide does a fantastic job of telling me how to install it, it doesn’t really tell me how it works, which is kinda my aim of doing this.

What I had in mind was to set up a server and poke around it under the guidance of some online tutorial. However, I couldn’t really find any material online that explains how certain files work. I tried reading the documentation page on github, but it doesn’t really tell me how it works either.

I understand that most people use irc clients instead of actually installing and maintaining a server, which may be part of the reason why I couldn’t find any material. So….would any kind soul help in giving me a primer in how this works? Or perhaps provide a link to some tutorial on charybdis? Thank you so much!!

Comment: "How it works" is a _very_ broad and vague question in this case. (And the answer frequently depends on what knowledge you already have or don't.) Where do you want to start and where do you want to go? Do you have specific files or settings which need explanation?

Comment: The source Code will reveal everything